# wxWidgets drawing failure

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

im using wxWidgets to create a simple GUI, but somehow it doesnt show what i want.

```
Frame::Frame(std::string title)
    :   wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    constexpr uint32 c_margin = 10;
    
    wxListView* listView_fileDrop_1     = new wxListView(this);
    wxListView* listView_fileDrop_2     = new wxListView(this);
    
    wxPanel* panel_diagramComparison    = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 200));
    wxPanel* panel_diagramLimit             = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 200));
    
    panel_diagramComparison->SetBackgroundColour(   wxColor(0,      255,    0));
    panel_diagramLimit->SetBackgroundColour(            wxColor(0,      0,      255));
    
    
    
    wxBoxSizer* boxSizer_fileDrop = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    boxSizer_fileDrop->Add(listView_fileDrop_1, 1, wxEXPAND,                        c_margin);
    boxSizer_fileDrop->Add(listView_fileDrop_2, 1, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT ,  c_margin);
    
    wxBoxSizer* boxSizer_window = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    boxSizer_window->Add(boxSizer_fileDrop,             0, wxEXPAND | wxTOP | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT, c_margin);
    boxSizer_window->Add(panel_diagramComparison, 1, wxEXPAND | wxTOP | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT, c_margin);
    boxSizer_window->Add(panel_diagramLimit,            1, wxEXPAND | wxALL,                                        c_margin);
    
    this->SetSizer(boxSizer_window);
    Maximize();
}
```

This is my Code so far, Frame is derived from wxFrame.
But the Output doesnt look expected, see the following link (im not allowed to embed Images because im new...):
https://ibb.co/TmCMwxG

What does the blue Rectangle in the top-left corner do there and how can i get it away?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is panel_diagramLimit and you created it.

Comment: I know that its that Panel, but it should be at the bottom, where it is too.
So why is it in the topleft corner too?

Comment: @leonue, you should call `Layout()``  at the end...

Comment: Nice, that helped. Now it works :)
Can you post your comment as an answer so i can mark it as solution?

Comment: @leonue, no need. Just update my comment...

Comment: Im new at Stackoverflow, how do i update your comment?

Comment: @leonue, on the left of my comment there is an up arrow. Click on it...

Comment: Sry, but on the left side of your comment theres just a red flag to report that comment.
The only arrow i see is left of your first answer, do you mean that one?